# can't find error android

Tags: android, logging

I have the following code:

```
Log.e("MainScreen", "1");  
ListAction listAction = new ListAction(this);
Log.e("MainScreen", "2");
```

The code only runs until it meets Log.e("MainScreen", "1").  Then it crashes.  However, I do not know how this is possible since the program never gets to the first line of the ListAction constructor (Log.e("ListAction", "1");)  Also, when I remove the ListAction listAction line, it goes on fine.

And the mentioned constructor:

```
public ListAction(Context context) {
    Log.e("ListAction", "1");
    this.db = new DataBaseCreation(context);
    Log.e("ListAction", "2");
    db.open();
    Log.e("ListAction", "3");
    this.bdd = db.getBDD();
    Log.e("ListAction", "4");
```

No Logs are posted when running the code.

What gives?  What is the problem?

Output:

```
03-26 03:54:54.680: E/MainScreen(534): 1

03-26 03:54:54.680: D/AndroidRuntime(534): Shutting down VM
03-26 03:54:54.690: W/dalvikvm(534): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-26 03:54:54.721: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 03:54:54.721: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.GroceryListManager/android.GroceryListManager.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 03:54:54.721: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any instance variables with initializers in class `ListAction`, the initializers will execute before the first line of the constructor. For instance, your class might look like this:

```
public class ListAction {
    public ListAction(Context context) {
        . . .
    }

    private Thing mThing = new Thing();
}
```

If one of the initializers (like `new Thing()`) raises an exception, that will produce the behavior you describe. It would help if you posted the logcat output of the crash.

Comment: - posted the logcat output of the crash

Comment: @user963070 - You're almost certainly referencing an instance variable that has a default value of `null` in the initializer for some other instance variable. Check every field initializer expression. Was that the entire logcat output? I'm surprised there's no source line identified.